# MySQL command to delete a row in C is not working

Tags: mysql, c

I don't usually code using C programming language but I learned it in school (so please bear with me because I am still a newbie).
In short, I was recently assigned to write code in C in order to delete rows from a table in MySQL database.

I used *stack**overflow*** and other resources to help me with this code!

This is my code (not all of it):

```
void delete_rows(MYSQL *con)
{
    char selection_query[256];
    char deletion_query[256];

    sprintf(selection_query, "SELECT id FROM <table> WHERE status = 'PROCESSING'\
    AND started < DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL %d DAY", expire_processing_days);
    if (mysql_query(con, selection_query))
    {
        finish_with_error(con);
    }

    MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(con);

    if (result == NULL) 
    {
        finish_with_error(con);
    }

    int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);

    MYSQL_ROW row; 

    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result))) 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < num_fields; i++) 
        { 
            printf("Deleting process with id: %s ", row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL");
            sprintf(deletion_query, "DELETE FROM <table> WHERE id = %d", row[i]);
            if (mysql_query(con, deletion_query))
            {
                finish_with_error(con);
            }
            mysql_commit(con);
        } 
            printf("\n"); 
    }

    mysql_free_result(result);
}

int main()
{
    MYSQL *con;
    DB_CONN_PARAMS *params = calloc(1,sizeof(DB_CONN_PARAMS));

    //just an alternative way of passing connection params, find a struct easier
    strcpy(params->host, <host>);
    strcpy(params->user, <user>);
    strcpy(params->pass, <password>);
    strcpy(params->db, <database>);

    MYSQL * connect_db(DB_CONN_PARAMS *params);
    con = connect_db(params);

    //we don't need the struct anymore
    free(params);
    params = NULL;

    //kill processes that are incomplete/hanging
    delete_rows(con);

    //close mysql connection
    mysql_close(con);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So, the code above compiles and runs without any errors, it prints out the ids of the rows that I want to delete. But when I go to the database to check the rows, they are still there!

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: A ***guess***? You can't call `mysql_query` while still fetching result from the previous query?

Comment: is there any kind of a transaction that's being started but not committed?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you should rather use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`, so you can avoid possible buffer overflows. Better yet, don't use string formatting at all, but rather *binding* of the parameters. Exactly how to do it with MySQL I don't know, but browse through their documentation or a few tutorials and it should become clear how to use it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but all previous queries are done, like the selection query. Am I wrong here?

Comment: @PhilM I don't think so, nothing to commit before this transaction!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the tips!

Comment: Maybe nothing before this transaction, but if the deletes are all part of a transaction that's being implicitly rolled back, then that might explain the problem. Just guessing, though; if you know there're no transactions being generated, then this obviously isn't the problem :)

Comment: What code is in mysql_query?

Comment: @Grantly, mysql_query is a function in the MySQL C API (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-query.html)

Comment: Perhaps call mysql_free_result(result) before you delete the rows

Comment: @Grantly, this doesn't work, but might have given me a hint that I am trying right now!

Comment: I found the problem. I posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have figured it out finally!
I changed the `%d` to `%s` in the following line:
`sprintf(deletion_query, "DELETE FROM  WHERE id = %d", row[i]);`.
Because `row[i]` is a string, I was blind to that.

I was able to figure it out by printing the whole MySQL command and noticed that the id passed is wrong!

Thank you everyone for your attempts to help me.

Comment: Yep, always print your statements to screen so you can analyse them when you get a problem like this. That immediately tells you whether the problem is with the C code, or transmission of the statement to the server. Divide and conquer!